# access an array within a structure

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having trouble in accessing an array within a structure. How can I access an array which is stored in a structure ? I have a structure, say,

```
@interface FoodDriveRow : NSObject
{
NSMutableArray *teamData;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSMutableArray *teamData;
@end

FoodDriveRow *row ;
```

now I want to access the array.

**Edit**

```
@interface TeamRow : NSObject
{
NSString *membername;
NSString *email;
NSString *phone;    
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *membername;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *phone;
@end
```

I am trying to store an object of TeamRow in to the array by

`[row.teamData insertObject:tRow atIndex:tIndex1];`

and want get the values from the array.

Thanks...

Comment: can you please give some more information

Comment: I think you need to learn more about Objective-C and Cocoa before asking such questions.

Comment: you only ask questions when you are learning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate the array, at the moment your array has a `nil` value.

Impliment `-(id)init`

Then within that you want to allocate your array and add some objects to it:

```
teamData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
TeamRow *teamRow = [[TeamRow alloc] init]; 
[teamData addObject:teamRow];
[teamRow release];
```

Now you can access objects:

```
TeamRow *retrievedTeamRow = [teamData objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FoodDriveRow* myDriveRow;
```

Use it as below , lets suppose you store NSString object in array

**For Adding**

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject

[myDriveRow.teamData  addObject:myString];
```

**For Removing**

```
(void)removeObject:(id)anObject
```

**For Accessing**

```
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Comment: ya thats true I can store values by [row.teamData insertObject:tRow atIndex:tIndex]; but I want to fetch the values from it

Comment: @maulik : Use -->  myObjectStoredInArray  =  [row.teamData objectAtIndex:tIndex];

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `[row.teamData objectAtIndex:0]` or from within the class itself, `[self.teamData objectAtIndex:0]`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand you but I think you can do this by `row.teamData`

Comment: by row.teamData I could not access the value of an array at specific index

Comment: [row.teamData objectAtIndex:indexValue]; will get you that

Answer (score 1):

```
[[row teamData] objectAtIndex: i];
```

where i is the index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a structure (`struct`) that you are referring to, it's a `class` called `FoodDriveRow` that descends directly from `NSObject`. In order to access properties from an object, you can use the old style:

```
[[row teamData] objectAtIndex:i]
```

Or you can use the new dot syntax:

```
[row.teamData objectAtIndex:i]
```